# How can i improve my CNN's accuracy evolution?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So, i'm trying to create a CNN which can predict if there is any "support devices" in a x-ray thorax image, but when training my model it seems it's not learning anything.

I'm using a dataset called "CheXpert" which has over 200.000 images to use. After doing some "cleaning", the final dataset ended up with 100.000 images.
As far as the model is concerned, i imported the convolutional base of the vgg16 pretrained model and added by my self 2 fully conected layers. Then, i freezed all the convolutional base and make only trainable the fully conected layers. Here's the code:

```
from keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.models import Model

pretrained_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

pretrained_model.summary()

for layer in pretrained_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

x = pretrained_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

dropout = Dropout(0.25)

# let's add a fully-connected layer
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = dropout(x)
x = Dense(1024, activation = 'relu')(x)
predictions = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

final_model = Model(inputs=pretrained_model.input, outputs=predictions)

final_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

As far as i know, the normal behavior should be that the accuracy should start low and then grow up with the epochs. But here it only oscillates through the same values (0.93 and 0.95). I'm sorry i cannot upload images to show you the graphs.

To sum up, i want to know if that little variance in the accuracy means that the model is not learning anything.

I have an hypothesis: from all the 100.000 images of the dataset, 95.000 have the label "1" and only 5.000 have the label "0". I think that if diminish the images with "1" equate them with the images with "0" the results would change.

Answer (score 0):

The lack of images labeled "0" doesn't help the CNN for sure. I also suggest to lower the learning rate and play around with the batch size to see if something changes.
I wish it helps.

Comment: not sure but based on the above- maybe just a general good framework for doing stuff like this is: https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner
??

Comment: You can manually set the learning rate of your rmsprop optimizer to eventually improve the accuracy. Check here https://keras.io/optimizers/ (for rmsprop the default lr is 0.001)

Answer (score 0):

Because of imbalance training data, I suggest that you can set "class_weight" during the training step. The more data you have, the lower class_weight you set.

```
class_weight = {0: 1.5, 1: 0.5}
model.fit(X, Y, class_weight=class_weight)
```

You can check the augment of class_weight in [keras document](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/).

> class_weight: Optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers) to
> a weight (float) value, used for weighting the loss function (during
> training only). This can be useful to tell the model to "pay more
> attention" to samples from an under-represented class.